# Customize probability for randomly generated string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function generateScramble(nMin = 20, nMax = 25) {
  
 const notations = [" U", " D", " R", " L", " F", " B"];
  const switches = ["", "\'", "2"];

  let last = null;
  let scrambles = "";
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * (nMax - nMin + 1) + nMin);
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //subtract 1 when you can't select the same as the last
    let available_notations = notations.length - (last === null ? 0 : 1);

    //one random for all combinations
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * available_notations * switches.length);

    let nt = Math.floor(random / switches.length); //notation value
    let sw = Math.floor(random % switches.length); //switch value

    if (last !== null && last <= nt) nt += 1; //add 1 when value bigger than last
    last = nt;

    scrambles += notations[nt] + switches[sw];
  }
  console.log(scrambles);
}
```

I have this code above that generates random strings like this

`R' L' B2 U' R' L R F' U R2 F2 B2 R B2 R2 L' R2 U' F' B`

But I don't want a specific letter to be beside a specific letter, for example I don't want `R'` to be beside of `L` (like `R' L`), or `F2` to be next to `B`.

I'm wondering is there any simple way to do this ?

Comment: Do you want to prevent U/ D, L/ R, F/ B being adjacent ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie yes that is correct :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a graph of possible legitimate moves:

```
const notationGraph = {
  "U": ["U", "L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "D": ["D", "L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "L": ["U", "D", "L", "F", "B"],
  "R": ["U", "D", "R", "F", "B"],
  "F": ["U", "D", "L", "R", "F"],
  "B": ["U", "D", "L", "R", "B"],
};
```

In your loop, use the previous `notation` as a key into the graph to get the possible next legitimate move. On the first move, use the keys of `notationGraph` as the starting array as we will assume any move is possible on the first go.

```js
const switches = ["", "\'", "2"]; 

const notationGraph = {
  "U": ["U", "L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "D": ["D", "L", "R", "F", "B"],
  "L": ["U", "D", "L", "F", "B"],
  "R": ["U", "D", "R", "F", "B"],
  "F": ["U", "D", "L", "R", "F"],
  "B": ["U", "D", "L", "R", "B"],
};

function randItem(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function generateScramble(len) {
  let scrambles = []; 
  let prev;
  for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
    let notation = randItem(prev ? notationGraph[prev] : Object.keys(notationGraph));
    let swtch = randItem(switches);
    scrambles.push(`${notation}${swtch}`);
    prev = notation;
  }
  return scrambles.join(" ");
}

function test() {
  console.log(generateScramble(10));  
  console.log(generateScramble(12));  
  console.log(generateScramble(14));  
  console.log(generateScramble(16));  
  console.log(generateScramble(18));  
}

test();
```

If you don't want `U` to follow `U` then just remove it from the array that is the property of `U` in `notationGraph` .